# Call onitemselected method from a button press event

Tags: android

I have an activity which has a spinner and this is the method that handles a selection of on item within that spinner.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {

             // Do stuff based on selection 
    }       
}
```

Further on I have a button and the code looks like this

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

    btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                            // This doesnt work
            onItemSelected(MyProfileActivity.this, v, 0, 2);

        }
    });
}
```

So essentially what I'm trying to do is simulate an item being selected in the spinner via a button press. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `onItemSelected` method on Button Click you should use `View.performItemClick` method to click on Spinner Item on Button Click do it as:

```
int item_postion=0;// item which you want to click
your_spinner.setSelection(item_postion, true);
View item_view = (View)your_spinner.getChildAt(item_postion);
long item_id = your_spinner.getAdapter().getItemId(item_postion);
your_spinner.performItemClick(item_view, 0, item_id);
```

Comment: Perfect this did what I wanted! I probably should of mentioned in my initial question that what I was really focused on was running the code that is in the onItemSelected method. I could have just copy and pasted all that code into the onClick method but that would of been unnecessary duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

               spinner.setSelection(index);  // which you what set the spinner position

               String item = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();  //which you need to get the selected item from the spinner 

               System.out.println("Selected item : "+item):

      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    spin.performItemClick(view, position, id);
```